# Set the direction of network circle graph to clockwise

Tags: r, igraph

I have the graph below in which I always display node `a` on top. What I would like to change is to change the direction of the circle network to be always right (clockwise) with `igraph`. Here is an example based on  [Set the position of certain node always on top of ring graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66709872/set-the-position-of-certain-node-always-on-top-of-ring-graph/66710742#66710742)

[image]

```
library('igraph')
nodes <- c('a','b','c','d')
x <- c(0,1,2,3)
y <- c(0,1,2,3)
from <- c('a','b','c','d')
to <- c('b','c','d','a')
NodeList <- data.frame(nodes, x ,y)
EdgeList <- data.frame(from, to)
a<- graph_from_data_frame(vertices = NodeList, d= EdgeList, directed = TRUE)

# rotate rows of matrix mat so that row number mx is at top
# where mx defaults to row having largest value in 2nd column
rot <- function(mat, mx = which.max(mat[, 2])) {
  if (mx == 1) mat else mat[c(mx:nrow(mat), 1:(mx-1)), ]
}
plot(a, layout = rot(layout_in_circle(a)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can determine the direction with the `order` argument:

```
plot(a, layout = rot(layout_in_circle(a, order = order(from,decreasing = T))))
```

[image]
Note that `order(from, decreasing =T)` works here because node names are in an increasing alphabetical order.
For a more general solution, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66793414/13513328).

Comment: maybe look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66791483/setting-the-order-of-circle-layout-to-decreasing-changes-the-nodes-position-in-t

Answer (score 2):

`ggraph` does this by default

```r
library(ggraph)

ggraph(a, layout = 'linear', circular = TRUE) +
  geom_edge_link(arrow = arrow(length = unit(4, 'mm')), end_cap = circle(4, 'mm')) +
  geom_node_label(aes(label = name)) +
  coord_fixed()
```

[image]

You can set positions manually as well:

```r
library(ggraph)
library(tidygraph)

a %>% 
  as_tbl_graph() %>% 
  mutate(
    alpha = pi/2 - 0:(gsize(a) - 1)*2*pi/gsize(a),
    x = cos(alpha),
    y = sin(alpha)
  ) %>% 
  ggraph(x = x, y = y) +
  geom_edge_link(arrow = arrow(length = unit(4, 'mm')), end_cap = circle(4, 'mm')) +
  geom_node_label(aes(label = name)) +
  coord_fixed()
```

[image]

Comment: useful indeed I wanted igraph but i ll keep that in mind